# Independence and expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I have a theorem that says

> If two random variables $X,Y$ are independent, then for any non-negative measurable functions $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:E\to\mathbb{R}$ the following holds
>   $$\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)]=\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]$$

But this does not imply that if $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ then automatically are $X$ and $Y$ independent, right? And is there an example?

If it is true, then is this because the identity function $f:x\to x$ is not non-negative?

Comment: Take $X$ uniform on $[-1,1]$.  Then let $Y=X^2$.

Comment: Incidentally -- your theorem gives an implication, but this actually is an equivalence (iff).

Comment: Or if you want $X$ and $Y$ to be non-negative as well, take $X$ uniform on $[0,2]$ and $Y = (X-1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition
$E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$
is equivalent to the condition that $X$ and $Y$ are *uncorrelated*.

It is true that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then they are uncorrelated. You are asking whether the converse is true, i.e., whether variables that are uncorrelated are necessarily independent. The answer is no.

There are many counterexamples; for example if $(X,Y)$ are uniformly distributed over the disk $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le1\}$, then $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated but not independent. Another example: let $(X,Y)$ be discrete random variables placing mass $\frac14$ on the four points $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,-1)$, $(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem is of the form

> If $X,Y$ independent, then for all nonnegative functions we have an equality

you ask whether this implies about

> If we have the equality for a specific function (which is not even non-negative), then $X,Y$ independent

The fact that the identity is not non-negative is only one of at least three points that prevent this inference from being valid